# Registering Javascript block in the codebehind: RegisterClientScriptBlock issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

**SCENARIO**

The BasePage.cs implements System.Web.UI.Page. It is a superclass without aspx from where **all actual pages** are derived.

I am registering some javascript in the BasePage using [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx):

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    Type csType = this.GetType();
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, "handler", @"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Something stupid!');</script>");
  }
}
```

I tested this snippet in a mock: it works right. Then I inserted the snippet in the BasePage.cs. In the index.aspx the script is not executed. Browser debugging shows that:

- no script has been registered
- no console error is displayed

In all other pages it works right.

**QUESTION**

Is there any specific issue related to the `RegisterClientScriptBlock()` method?

**REMARK**

I am sorry, but I am not allowed to post the whole index.aspx page code. But maybe if you have a clue then I can give you further details.

Comment: _Where_ in `BasePage` is this code? Does the codebehind of `index.aspx` inherit `BasePage` or `Page`? Does the codebehind of `index.aspx` override the method which calls `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and not call the `base` version?

Comment: @ Rawling: as I said, all the pages inherit from BasePage. I added some context in the code snippet. The page_load method is overridden in the index.aspx page, but the base.Page_Load(sender, e) is executed first.

Comment: Try taking the `virtual` out of your `Page_Load` definition(s) - I think that might be your problem.

Comment: Does it behaving any differently if moved into the page_init method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually a collegue of mine suggested to wrap the index.aspx markup with the `form` tag. That is enough and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the option ViewSource in the browser. It will help you findout how the script is  written as the final output.

Comment: some details added regarding client-side debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As I've commented: I believe marking your `Page_Load` as `virtual` may mean your descendant pages are somehow overriding it, then not calling the `base` (`Base Page`) version, causing the script not to be registered.

Comment: I have removed the "virtual" modifier, but nothing changes in the index.aspx. Nice try.

Comment: OK. It's very unusual to see `virtual` there so I thought this was worth a try :)